# Finding a Dominant Cluster

Tags: normal-distribution, clustering, gaussian-mixture-distribution

Super-basic question here:

I'm looking for a way to find the dominant cluster of a set of clusters (as in the first image):

[image]

This is *not* what I get when I run a Gaussian Mixture model with one component (it tries to cover everything):
[image]

I'm sure there's a standard approach for doing this, I just don't know what it's called.

---

The approach I'm thinking of is to maximize the sum of likelihoods of all points under a normal distribution:

If $x \in \mathcal R^{N\times D}$ is my dataset

$\mathcal L = \sum_n \det(\Sigma)^{-1/2}  \exp\left(-\frac12 (x_n-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x_n-\mu)\right)$

and then find equations for $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ when $\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \mu}=0$ and $\frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \Sigma}=0$, and solving with fixed-point iteration.  What that's led to so far, unless there's an error in my implementation (possible), is that the cluster moves to the correct mean but then collapses over iterations towards zero variance. This I suppose makes sense, because under this formulation the maximum likelihood is obtained by having a zero-variance gaussian on one point.

**Is there a name for this type of problem, and if so what is the common approach?**

Comment: Have you considered using more then one cluster to model, but only keeping the largest?

Comment: I have, but it seems awkward, because (1) I don't necessarily know how many clusters exist in advance, (2) it's not clear how this would behave when some of the data is just "background" and not generated in clusters.

Comment: You could use DBSCAN which will determine the number of clusters for you and will identify noise points.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, here is what you can do, self:

Change the function you are trying to maximize to:

$\mathcal L = \sum_n \sqrt{ \det(\Sigma)^{-1/2}  \exp\left(-\frac12 (x_n-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x_n-\mu)\right)}$

This will encourage the inclusion of more points, but not so many that it tries to cover everything.